# 3D Shape with only coplanar faces?

Tags: 3d, geometry

I just thought of this problem, and it's bugging me that I can't find any sort of shape that fits it.

*Are there any 3D shapes with only faces that have coplanar matches with other faces in the shape?*

If I must make myself clear (because I'm pretty sure my terminology is indescript and probably completely wrong), when I say "coplanar faces", I mean faces that can have a ruler lay flat across them. So, not parallel or intersecting. Each face in the shape must have at least one coplanar match.

Thanks a whole bunch in advance.

Edit: Rahul has found a shape that fits the description (the small stellated dodecahedron with the faces interpreted to be triangles, see the comments below). Thanks, Rahul!

Comment: Like [this shape](https://www.rubiks.com/images/products/123/rub_-_5__enlarged.jpg) with $54$ square faces? :)

Comment: For a nontrivial example, interpret the [small stellated dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Small_stellated_dodecahedron.png) as having $60$ triangular faces instead of $12$ pentagrammic faces.

Comment: The square faces of the individual cubes would all have coplanar faces, but the interior connectors would also have to be coplanar. Whenever I try to construct a shape that would fit these requirements, the shape seems to have to repeat itself forever, if that makes sense. If you essentially separated the cube's faces in space and tried to connect them by forming other faces around them, would you be left with faces without coplanar matches?

Comment: Sorry, that was a misleading image. I meant [this](http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/EMT668/emt668.student.folders/SeitzBrian/EMT669/painted.cube/image1.gif). No interior connectors.

Comment: Are coplanar faces 'allowed' to share sides? If so, that diagram would certainly solve this, but I wouldn't think that to be true. If I'm wrong (which I most likely am on that assumption), please explain why.

Comment: Oh, the small stellated dodecahedron seems to fit the bill. Is there a name or classification for this type of shape?